# How do I input a character then move it up a few letters in the English alphabet

Tags: java, string, algorithm

How do I input a character then move it up a few letters in the English alphabet. I know how to grab a letter from a string. But I need then to move that letter up 2 characters in the English alphabet

So:

`A` would `C`
`C` would `E`

How can I do this?

Comment: +1 for that @MarounMaroun!

Comment: @bobbel +1 for the +1 on my +2.

Comment: This trick here is how to wrap y->a and z->b

Comment: @MarounMaroun Upvoteception

Answer (score 1):

I believe chars and ints are interchangeable, have you tried: `char d = c + 2` where c is a char?

```
char c = 'A';
c += 2;
System.out.println(c);
```

Prints `C`

Comment: Be careful with the bounds.. `'z' + 2` will exceed the alphabet chars in the ASCII table.

Comment: try `c += c > 'X' ? -24 : 2;`

Comment: Yeah, that would work and keeps it relatively simple; you could also use `mod` `(%)` but that makes it a bit more unreadable.

Comment: Unfortunately you need a typecast: `c = (char) ('A' + (c - 'A' + 2) % 26);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher):

**Code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str = "ABCXYZ";
  System.out.println(encrypt(str, 2));
}

public static String encrypt(String str, int n) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    sb.append((char) ((c + n - 'A') % 26 + 'A'));
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

**Output**:

```
CDEZAB
```

Comment: Could you explain this part `(c + n - 'A') % 26 + 'A')` please? I am a little confused about that, and why `(c - n + 'A') % 26 + 'A')` will shift the letters back.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the caesar method, where `s=yourword` and `k=movedByNumberinAlphabet`:

```
public class CaesarChiffre {

    private String[] alphabet = { "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j",
            "k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
            "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};

    public CaesarChiffre() {
        System.out.println(caesarChiffre("hello", 2));
    }

    public String caesarChiffre(String s, int k) {
        if (k<0) {
            k = this.alphabet.length + k;
        }
        String[] c = new String[s.length()];
        String t = "";
        int [] n = new int[s.length()];

        for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++) {
            c[i] = s.substring(i,i+1);
            for(int j = 0 ; j < this.alphabet.length ; j++) {
                if(c[i].equalsIgnoreCase(this.alphabet[j])) {
                    n[i] = (j+k) % this.alphabet.length;
                }   
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++) {
            c[i] = this.alphabet[n[i]];
            t = t + c[i];
        }
        return t.trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple method with a modulo approach (only valid for A-Za-z range):

```
public static char moveUpChar(final char c, final int i) {
    int offset, range;
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        offset = 'A';
        range = 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
    } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
        offset = 'a';
        range = 'z' - 'a' + 1;
    } else {
        throw new InvalidParameterException("Invalid character: " + c);
    }
    int abs = c - offset;
    abs = (abs + i) % range;
    return (char) (abs + offset);
}
```

Test main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("a + 2 = " + moveUpChar('a', 2));
    System.out.println("A + 2 = " + moveUpChar('A', 2));
    System.out.println("J + 7 = " + moveUpChar('J', 7));
    System.out.println("y + 2 = " + moveUpChar('y', 2));
    System.out.println("z + 3 = " + moveUpChar('z', 3));
    System.out.println("Y + 4 = " + moveUpChar('Y', 4));
    System.out.println("Z + 1 = " + moveUpChar('Z', 1));
}
```

Output:

```
a + 2 = c
A + 2 = C
J + 7 = Q
y + 2 = a
z + 3 = c
Y + 4 = C
Z + 1 = A
```